# Fetching Incorrect Location for tablet Devices using location Flutter

Tags: flutter, location

Trying to fetch current location but getting incorrect results for tablet devices, It is working fine for mobile devices.
It is not showing any errors for tablets.

Result from Mobile Device: 18.5658874,73.7741657 (Correct Result)
Result from Tablet Device: 37.4220936, -122.083922

Expecting same results for mobile and tablet Devices

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you look up that location, you will see it is on the Google campus. The emulated tablet device always gives these coordinates.